# Função que compara caracteres de uma string e retorna verdadeiro ou falso

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Estou tentando fazer uma função que deveria retornar verdadeiro ou falso caso o primeiro e último caracteres sejam iguais.

Porém, ao compará-las está dando erro de *out of range* e eu não consigo identificar o motivo:

```
def first_and_last(message):
    if(message[0] == message[-1]):
       return True
    return False
print(first_and_last("else")) #should return True
print(first_and_last("tree")) #should return False
print(first_and_last("")) #should return True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dá erro de *out of range* porque a última string é vazia, ou seja, o tamanho dela é zero. Sendo assim, ela não tem nenhum índice (não tem `message[0]`, nem `message[-1]`, nem qualquer outro valor), e qualquer tentativa de obter algum caractere dela dará erro.

Para solucionar, você pode testar se a string é vazia e retornar `True`, caso contrário, retorne o resultado da comparação:

```
def first_and_last(message):
    if not message: # string vazia, retorna True
        return True
    return message[0] == message[-1]

print(first_and_last("else")) # True
print(first_and_last("tree")) # False
print(first_and_last("")) # True
```

O `if not message` testa se a string é vazia. Isso é possível porque [uma string vazia é considerada um valor falso](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

Depois, se a string não for vazia, retorne o resultado da comparação do primeiro com o último caractere. Repare que não precisa do `if` aqui, pois o resultado da comparação `message[0] == message[-1]` já é um *booleano* e você pode retorná-lo diretamente.

De forma geral, qualquer expressão desta forma:

```
if condição:
    return True
return False
```

Pode ser substituída por:

```
return condição
```

Por isso que em vez de:

```
if(message[0] == message[-1]):
   return True
return False
```

Eu fiz simplesmente:

```
return message[0] == message[-1]
```

---

Por fim, dá para simplificar as duas condições assim:

```
def first_and_last(message):
    return not message or message[0] == message[-1]
```

Ou seja, retorna o resultado de `not message or message[0] == message[-1]` (string é vazia, **ou** o primeiro e último caracteres são iguais).

Este caso não dá erro porque o operador `or` é um [*short-circuit operator*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not): se a primeira condição for verdadeira, ele nem verifica a segunda. Então primeiro eu verifico se a string é vazia. Caso ela não seja, aí a segunda condição é verificada. Mas se a string for vazia, a expressão já retorna `True`, não correndo o risco de dar o erro de *out of bounds*.

Comment: Muito obrigado!
Me esclareceu muito!

Comment: @DanielMcCarthy Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. E quando tiver 15 pontos, [**vc também poderá votar**](/help/privileges/vote-up) em todas as respostas que achou úteis.

Answer (score 1):

Outra forma de se resolver esta questão é:

```
def first_and_last(message):
    if len(message) != 0:
        if message[0] == message[-1]:
            return True
        return False
    return True


palavra = input('Digite uma palavra: ')

print(f'\033[32m{first_and_last(palavra)}')
```

Observe que quando é executado este código recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite uma palavra`. Neste momento devemos digitar a palavra desejada e pressionar `ente`.

Neste momento a palavra e capturada como `string` e enviada para a função `first_and_last`. Chegando lá, é verificado seu tamanho. Caso o tamanho da string seja **0**, isto é, a string seja vazia, o retorno será **True**. Caso a string não seja vazia, será verificado se a primeira e última letra da string são iguais. Caso positivo a função retorna **True** e, caso negativo, a função retorna **False**.

**Observação**

Quando a string é vazia, o seu tamanho será `0`. Isto significa dizer que tanto a letra `inicial` quanto a letra `final` são iguais a `vazio`.